# How to type an object whose keys are a subset of the keys of the another type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a type like this:

```js
type Metadata = {
  name: string;
  size: number;
  date: string;
  language: string;
  formattedName: string;
  normalizedDate: string
};
```

and now I need to build this constant:

```js
const main = {
  name: ["main", "master"],
  size: ["size"],
  date: ["date"],
  language: ["lang", "language"]
} as ??? // as Record<keyof Metadata, string[]>;
```

that is an object whose keys are a subset of the keys of the type Metadata and the values are an array of string.
How can I type the `main` object? I tried `Partials(Metadata)` but it seems to be not right.
Which is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can say that this type must "satisfy" or be at least assignable to another type, without actually overriding the inferred type information with the new `satisfies` keyword in 4.9+:

```
const main = {
  name: ["main", "master"],
  size: ["size"],
  date: ["date"],
  language: ["lang", "language"]
} satisfies Partial<Record<keyof Metadata, string[]>>;
```